# implementing xmp data or dng data on other images in mobile app

Tags: react-native, xmp, lightroom, dng

I'm trying to build a mobile app (react-native or native languages) that will be able to take xmp file (in other words is presets of photos) and implement its data on other photo, or implementing dng settings on another photo.

What I'm trying to understand if that is even possible, to use Lightroom presets outside of Lightroom App.
Did someone here succeed to implement his\her own Lightroom preset without using Lightroom on mobile?

Comment: Hello Eden, I'm trying to do that as well. Did you find a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think so cuz every app has different sets of editing skills, the best I think you could do is to create an app from where a user will click on DNG and it will open in Lightroom.